# Spring Cache Abstraction for Write - Behind Caching Strategy

Tags: caching, ehcache, ignite

I am new to Spring cache abstraction. I have explored it using ehcache and apache ignite caching providers.

I want to know if spring cache abstraction supports the caching strategies of Write-behind and write-through.

Thanks,
bs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct support for *cache-through* in the declarative Spring abstraction.

And in a way it makes sense, since the abstraction lets you surround methods with caching related annotations. But with a *cache-through* pattern, the whole method would only be a cache interaction: a `get` for read, or a `put` for write. Not the if-then-else that the annotation abstracts.

However, if you use the `CacheManager` and `Cache` interfaces provided by Spring directly in your code, you can perfectly use them in a *cache-through* way.

Answer (score 1):

Ignite cache has a notion of `CacheStore` interface that used in cases when there is a need to wire the cache with a persistent store (RDBMS, MongoDB, Hadoop, etc.). This interface provides write-through/write-behind and read-through semantics. Please refer to [this documentation](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/persistent-store) for more details.

Also I would recommend taking look at [various examples](https://github.com/apache/ignite/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/store) that demonstrates how particular `CacheStore` implementations are used in Ignite. The examples are available in Ignite release bundles.